# Can gzip tar files be used for training data in Sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have 50TB of uncompressed data (images) that is in dozens of tar.gz files in S3. I'm training tensorflow models with a dozen of these tar.gz files at a time. I would like to use a Sagemaker training job to pull this data and unpack it before training. Is this possible? Do I have to change the way that the data is stored before running training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer** : No

**Long Answer**:
The recommended way to use Sagemaker with very large datasets is to use the Pipe API (as opposed to the File Api) which streams data to the training image rather than downloading the data. To take advantage of the Pipe API the data will need to be in one of the supported file types: **text records, TFRecord or Protobuf**

The benefits are

1. reducing delay when the container is launched
2. not needing to scale the instance storage to the size of the training data
3. increasing throughput by moving most preprocessing before model training

References:

1. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-pipe-input-mode-for-amazon-sagemaker-algorithms/
2. https://julsimon.medium.com/making-amazon-sagemaker-and-tensorflow-work-for-you-893365184233 (This is a fantastic resource which answers a lot of questions regarding using Sagemaker on very large datasets)
3. https://julsimon.medium.com/deep-dive-on-tensorflow-training-with-amazon-sagemaker-and-amazon-s3-12038828075c

Comment: Is this answer still valid?
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/inputs.html states that compression parameter of Input is used only in Pipe input mode and it can be 'Gzip' or None